# How to delete a partition that is locked

Tags: partitioning, gparted, live-cd, delete

I wish to delete a partition of Linux Mint. I am familiar with Gparted and using a live cd, but it is locked. It says extended /dev/sda2. Here is a screenshot of my partitions:

[image: Gparted]  Thank you all for your help in advance.

Comment: Right click on the partition and select unlock?

Comment: Maybe swap is mounted and you have to unmount swap or swap-off to unmount extended partition. Any partition mounted in extended mounts the extended. And live installer usually mounts swap to speed up things.

Comment: You better make a screenshot of gparted and post it to your question.

Comment: add the output `sudo parted -l` to your question.

Comment: Your sda5 and sda6 partitions are inside sda2 partition. Are you sure you want to delete them all?

Comment: Linux Mint freezes on the mouse and the keyboard doesn't work. I like Ubuntu better.

Comment: @oldfred, you were right swap was mounted. If you make it an answer I will vote it.

Comment: if you delete /dev/sda2 you will delete `linux-swap` along with it, linux-swap is used by Ubuntu an Linux distros it can work without it but it's better be there. Rather simply format /dev/sda6 which I assume contains Linux Mint.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't delete or move partitions that are mounted. If you don't want to delete a system partition, where your working system is installed, then right-click it and choose "unmount". If you want to delete a system partition, then you will have to boot from some other drive, like LiveCD.

If your linux Mint is on sda6 prtition, then just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's THE **extended** partition, you can't delete it without removing all the logical partitions in it.

You need to unmount all partitions in the *extended* partition that may be mounted.

In your case, you need to unmount **swap** partition. Right-click on it and choose **unmount**. Then proceed.

Comment: Are you saying that if I remove it I will also remove Ubuntu?

Comment: So you certainly are attempting to delete the wrong partition